# Is nested alt in sequence diagram a good practice?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have created a sequence diagram, and found it has multiple nested alt.

[image]

Is this a good or bad practice?

If it is a bad practice, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The good, the bad and the ugly

It is difficult to give advice about good and bad practices without objective criteria, and these will depend on the **purpose of the diagram**:

- If you use UML for some kind of **visual programming**, where a comprehensive diagram should show all the details of a specific interaction, nested `alt` could be a ***good*** practice if there is no alternative.  Since different lifelines are driving independent alternatives (`FusionAuth` the outer `alt`,  `Occupations` the inner one), the nesting represents the behavioral logic appropriately. But if a same lifeline would drive decision, a flattened `alt` could a be a more readable way, trading the more complex nesting against more but simpler branches.
- If you use UML to **communicate and to reason** about a system,  the diagrams should be easily understood:  nesting would be a ***bad*** practice, since it adds a level of complexity.

We fortunately have avoided the ***ugly***: identical nested `alt` in several branches.

### Alternatives to nested alt

The UML secret is to have more diagrams but smaller ones, each focusing on a single aspect.  You can find this advice at the end of almost every chapter of Booch, Jacobson and Rumbaugh's book *The UML User guide*.

Two strategies are applicable here:

- Diagrams per scenario: the main success scenario would be one diagram,  and the different failure scenarios would be the others.  Super-easy to read.
- [Separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/): Different concerns would be addressed in different diagrams you could for example separate the use of `Occupations` by its clients and the way `Occupations` does its business:  separate `Manager`, `Client`, `Occupations`,  and `Occupations`, `FusionAuth` and `Database` in two diagrams; You'd avoid nested `alt`, the inner one being in the second diagram and not necessarily relevant for the same audience.

**Remark**: I'm not a big fan of visual programming.  But if you are, the second strategy is fully compatible with it, with the advantage of preventing the *ugly* repeating of the same nested fragments in several places.

Comment: The first strategy is easy to implement but results in a lot of diagrams and is hard to manage. The second strategy is great but hard to implement for not-so-experience dev like me, but it's worth the try :)

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn it may be hard to implement with lack of experience, because it's not obvious to identify the concerns and see how to best decouple. But it's really worth a try, because separation of concerns is more general than modeling.  And sometimes it's difficult to decouple the diagrams because of flaws in the underlying design.  The more you try,  the better your design skills will improve.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can do that and it will be okay. However, once you start doing that you are in danger to fall in graphical programming. Once upon a time people dreamed of graphical programming as *the* solution for the future. Simply, it isn't. Code is much denser and easier to read. So don't start writing programs that way.

Now for the use of that construct. Where ever you want to show some complex collaboration a graphical overview of the participants will be most helpful. But only if you stick to the most important part of tha communication. Rather than nesting fragments it's better to have different SDs to focus. You can use message endpoints to cross between detail diagrams. Again, it depends on how you make the split. It needs some experience to find the golden ratio.

Comment: I totally agree about graphical programming.  Better use UML fro showing things that are not easily found in the code.  Completely in the spirit: https://twitter.com/Grady_Booch/status/1388930413280727042?s=20

Comment: @Christophe I remember trying an attempt in the early 80s about graphical programming an soon stoppred going that way. Ever since I had the creep when using graphical programming which luckily where always short ugly encounters.